# Protecting modules from deletion or editing

Tags: module, acl, administration, module-manager

Does anyone know a way to protect a custom module in it entirety (position, content and from being unpublished and or deleted)

I have a module that I don't want other users from altering the file in anyway due to it being a terms and conditions module.

Comment: By default in Joomla, you can only prevent a usergroup from being able to perform actions in the entire Module Manager, not individual modules. For this, you'll need to use a 3rd party extension. I've tested Advanced Module Manager free and it's still not possible, but the Pro version may support it, so I'd suggestion contacting the developer over at Regular Labs: https://www.regularlabs.com/

Comment: @Lodder - that's not true - There is a long time now that Joomla provides permissions per module.

Answer (score 1):

In recent Joomla versions (3.2 and later), modules come with a permissions tab, where you can set the following permissions per user-group:

- Delete
- Edit
- Edit State
- Front-end Editing

[image: Edit Module - Permissions]

Of course you need a ACL organization in place - as if all of your editing users are Super-Users then you can't restrict them from accessing the module.